# Select an ARIMA model for oil price based on ACF/PACF

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

I build an ARIMA model to predict price oil from a monthly data. After differencing the time series it become stationary with d =  1. But in order to identify the AR order and MA order the PACF is not significant until lag 18 and the ACF in not significant at all as shown below.

How do I interpret this? Should I use ARIMA(0,1,0) or could there be a seasonal pattern here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: From ACF and PACF this looks pretty much like ARIMA(0,1,0). Also, consider using capital letters and punctuation as is appropriate.

Comment: As mentioned above, most likely it's a random process. Check it for seasonality, but I wouldn't expect much. Nevertheless, if modeling this exact series is important for any reason, I would check for nonlinearities in the series, might appear to be some sort of threshold model.